# operator [ ] recursion

Tags: c++, linked-list

I need help creating a recursive definition for operator [] for a linked list.

LN has a int value and a next pointer

```
int & operator[] (int i, LN*l, int &k){
   int k = 0;
   //check if list is empty
   if(l == 0)
   return -1;
   //base case
   if(k == i)
   return l->value;
   else
   //I need to traverse through the linked list until I reach the ith position
   return operator[](i, l->next, ++k);
}
```

Am I on the right track? Is there a way I could eliminate the k variable?
//make this a member function
Assuming that there is a private LN* head

```
 int & operator[](int &i){
    {
        LN* temp = head;
        if(i < 0 || temp ==0)
           return -1;
        if(i == 0)
           return temp->value;
        else{
           temp = temp->next;
           return operator[](--i);
        }

   }
```

Comment: You're shadowing k here, have you noticed?

Comment: Why can't you simply decrement `i` and check for when it gets to `0`?

Comment: Would this make more sense as a member function of a class instead of passing the list node as an argument?

Comment: you should not implement this as recursive functions since it can easily be implemented as loop. on large lists you may run out of stack if you want to iterate to high-index-elements

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of `k` (both the parameter and the local variable), by passing `i-1` in your recursive call along with l->next. Then when `i` is 0 you know you want the current item.

```
return operator[](i-1, l->next);
```

You should also add some checks to make sure i isn't less than zero.

Also note - recursion isn't really helping here, you could more easily do this in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite it as:

```
int & operator[] (int i, LN* l){
   if(i == 0) return l->value;
   else return operator[](i - 1, l->next);
}
```

that is: decrement the `i` variable until we reach `0` (that means we have moved to the next `i` times).

Also if you want the syntactic sugar that is `list[i]` you should make this a member function of your list class.

On a side note you should use [`std::list<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) or [`std::forward_list<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) instead of creating your own implementation.

Finally you should notice that linked-lists, in general, are really not meant to be randomly accessed. You should an array based container instead.

Comment: parameter `l` could have `head` as it default value